# Does CyanogenMod support the Google Play Store and Google Account integration?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4

As it says. I am looking into CyanogenMod as a stopgap measure before I upgrade to an iPhone this year or the next. My current phone no longer gets updated and I cannot justify having year old bugs still active.

However, I have invested quite a bit of time in my current Android ecosystem and I both do not want to ditch that AND I want to be able to easily transfer my apps to the iPhone when I am setting the latter up, through the Apple transfer app. Are both an option when using CyanogenMod in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!,Gapps are supported in Canyogenmod. They are supported but you have to flash them instead of regularly installing them. You can find your flashible zip easily just google it.

Answer (score 2):

On a custom Os like Cyanogenmod you must flash the googleapps.zip from the recovery. The apps and services aren't built in but are very easy to flash.